# Matlab Continuously Crashes when Using Simulink

Tags: matlab, crash, simulink

Whenever I open simulink and start working on a model Matlab displays the following error and crashes:

```
MATLAB crash file:C:\Users\FARRUK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\matlab_crash_dump.3352-1:


------------------------------------------------------------------------
          Access violation detected at Thu Sep 11 01:50:23 2014
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding     : Disabled
  Default Encoding   : windows-1252
  MATLAB Architecture: win32
  MATLAB Root        : C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2014a
  MATLAB Version     : 8.3.0.532 (R2014a)
  Operating System   : Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro with Media Center
  Processor ID       : x86 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine    : Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM mixed mode
  Window System      : Version 6.3 (Build 9600)

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Access violation

Register State (from fault):
  EAX = 00000000  EBX = 00000000
  ECX = 33e66640  EDX = 6a76e250
  ESP = 2ad7cbf0  EBP = 33e66640
  ESI = 2ad7cc50  EDI = 00000000

  EIP = 6a76e253  EFL = 00010202

   CS = 00000023   DS = 0000002b   SS = 0000002b
   ES = 0000002b   FS = 00000053   GS = 0000002b
```

I tried it on both the 64 bit and 32 bit version but it keeps on crashing over and over again.

Comment: This looks like something you should forward to MathWorks support... I've also had some fatal java exceptions with R2014a and pre-release 14b, but not as often as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue with MATLAB R2014a.

The cause was an incorrect setting of the `IsFlat` property of the `Browser` structure in the `slblocks.m` file for a custom library. The problem was fixed when the value of `IsFlat` field was changed from `1` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered exactly the same problem with Matlab 2012, 2013 and 2014, but the issue was with linking to DLLs that were compiled as .NET and accessing members of a list.

For example, `x = someList.Item(0)` crashes Matlab. The .NET object internally makes use of the `new` modifier (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) for details). Any .NET DLL that returns objects with an embedded `new` modifier will crash Matlab.

Matlab does not fully comply with the .NET syntax. If you use third-party .NET DLLs that use `new` modifiers, you'll never know that this modifier is being used (since it's internal), nor will Matlab's crash report point to this issue. It just looks like an access violation. Matlab has yet to fix this.

Answer (score -1):

If there are further issues with such software, one very effective but risky way is to run them as administrator. It usually does the work, but as I mentioned earlier, it is risky since it gets access to many file paths that it initially wasn't. If it does solve your crashing problem that means that there were some files your software isn't able to access normally.